# Repeated internal errors in 12.04 - worth reporting every time?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

Almost every time I start up my Ubuntu 12.04 system I'm told about an internal error relating to Rhythmbox, which I have as a start-up application.

I've been opting to send an error report each time this happens, but I'm not sure if this useful - should I keep on reporting these errors month in, month out, until they're fixed, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is, indeed, useful to do. Because there is obviously something wrong and if you continue sending reports, whoever receives them can see what is going on. It might take ages for them to be able  to do anything about it but you are at least putting some effort in, even if just a button click.

**However**, you also might want to try disabling the Ubuntu One store and Magnatune store plugins, there is a confirmed bug that they can cause Rhythmbox to crash. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/820191)

I've also seen around that some of the other plugins such as Cover Art, Cover Art Search, and Replay Gain might be effecting the frequency of crashes, but I'm not entirely certain if disabling them will help or not.

In either case, you hopefully won't be getting these crashes and having to continuously send bug repots. :3 Idk if it will fix your problem, but it can't hurt to try.